Why don't my threads make my script run a shorter time?
import re
import concurrent.futures
import time

setting1 = 101
setting2 = 321
setting3 = None

threads = 1000

start = time.perf_counter()

def load_keywords(keyword_file):
    with open(keyword_file, 'r') as keywordhandle:
        keywords = [keyword.strip() for keyword in keywordhandle.readlines()]
    return keywords

def gencombo(user, keywords):
    og_user = re.sub(r'\d', '', user)
    user_lower = og_user.lower()
    combos = []
    n_keywords = []

    for keyword in keywords:
        if keyword.lower() in user_lower:
            n_keywords.append(keyword)

    for k1 in n_keywords:
        k1 = str(k1)
        for k2 in n_keywords:
            k2 = str(k2)
            if k2 in k1 and k2 is not k1:
                n_keywords.remove(k2)

    n_keywords.reverse()

    for k1 in n_keywords:
        k1 = str(k1)
        for k2 in n_keywords:
            k2 = str(k2)
            if k2 in k1 and k2 is not k1:
                n_keywords.remove(k2)

    for keyword in n_keywords:
        if keyword.lower() in user_lower:
            print(f"Combos added for: {user}")
            if setting1 is not None:
                combos.append(f"{user}:{keyword}{str(setting1)}")
            if setting2 is not None:
                combos.append(f"{user}:{keyword}{str(setting2)}")
            if setting3 is not None:
                combos.append(f"{user}:{keyword}{str(setting3)}")


    return '\n'.join(combos) if combos else None

def gencombos(input_file, output_file, keyword_file):
    keywords = load_keywords(keyword_file)
    with open(input_file, 'r') as combohandle:
        with open(output_file, 'w') as handlenone:
            def threadrun():
                for user in combohandle:
                    combo = gencombo(user.strip(), keywords)
                    if combo:
                        handlenone.write(f"{combo}\n")
            with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=threads) as executor:
                executor.submit(threadrun)

gencombos("users.txt", "output.txt", "keywords.txt")

finish = time.perf_counter()

input(f"Finished in {round(finish - start, 2)} seconds.")

I first tried using threading on its own, but then I found out that concurrent.futures helps run certain functions. As such, I switched to that. However, even after switching I found out that the number of my threads configured doesn't matter. It still runs around the same time. I was hoping one of you could help me, as I can't figure it out.

Your first Python script and you're trying to use multi-threading? Learn to walk before trying to run.

Threading doesn't generally increase speed of python programs, because threads don't run concurrently.

They do run concurrently, but not necessarily in parallel.

Yea, the threads run concurrently, but they cannot run parallel because the interpreter only allows single thread execution. They basically just pass the task around and take turns.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

I commend you for going a more complex route while trying to learn the language, but threading in Python, especially with something this simple, won't see a jump in performance almost ever. In fact, sometimes when you are using CPU-bound tasks like regex and looping lists, threading can actually slow the program down because of how the interpreter works.
1000 thread overhead is also quite a lot.
From a pure efficiency standpoint, you may find more success using multiprocessing rather than multithreading in a script like this. I don't necessarily want to rewrite this for you in a "better" way, but I suggest doing some reading and research about multiprocessing in Python environments.
